# iPod Classic 160GB 6th gen (2nd rev)

Tags: sync, ipod

Is there a way to sync a 6th gen iPod classic 160GB with Ubuntu? I have tried gtkpod with Rhythmbox and Banshee but it doesn't work, the songs are synced but it messes up the database, songs don't actually play.

Has anyone managed to make it work?

Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon an upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04, both gtkpod and Banshee successfully sync my iPod Classic 160GB 6th gen (2nd rev), including cover art.

Just run

```
sudo apt-get install gtkpod
```

I recommend using Banshee to sync music, it has a much nicer interface and is much more stable than the `gtkpod` GUI, but it uses `gtkpod` in the background.

It may not be necessary to upgrade to 15.04 to do this, perhaps it would be possible to just compile the latest version of `gtkpod` from [here](http://www.gtkpod.org/index.php?title=Download) (currently on version 2.1.5) to fix the problem, but I haven't tested this yet.